# Why is the Vacuum state got by a limit to imaginary time?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, path-integral, vacuum, propagator, wick-rotation

Given a (non-relativistic) propagator $K_t(A,B)$ giving the 'conditional amplitude' to go from state $B$ to state $A$ in time $t$, it is known that one can find the vacuum wavfunction by (independent of any $B$):

$$\Psi^t_{VAC}(A) = e^{iE_0t}\lim_{t\rightarrow i\infty} \frac{K_t(A,B)}{\sqrt{K_{2t}(B,B)}}$$

(The denominator is just there to make sure it is normalised to 1). $E_0$ is the vacuum energy got from:

$$i E_0 = \lim_{t\rightarrow i\infty} \frac{ \dot{K}_t(A,B) }{ K_t(A,B) }$$ for any $A$ and $B$. (Which is just got from considering that $i\dot{\psi}_{VAC}^0(A) = E_0 \psi_{VAC}^0(A)$ )

I think I first read of this "trick" in Hawking's paper about the no-boundary principle where it is expressed in terms of path integrals. (But in that case there is no "$B$" since there is no boundary in imaginary time!)

I suppose one can interpret this as a state, which after an infinite amount of (imaginary time) settles down to the vacuum state.

I have two questions.

(1) Is there any physical meaning that we are taking the limit to infinity along imaginary time? Or is this just a mathematical trick. I believe it is related to the fact that path integrals are only properly defined after a Wick rotation.

(2) Does this trick fail if there are multiple vacuums? My immediate guess is that if $K$ has poles then the different vacuum solutions would correspond somehow to different paths around the poles. But that is just a wild guess. Another guess would be that for different sets of states $B$ would go to different vacuums. The vacuums being like attractors. (Although this would seem to make path integrals multi-valued!)

Comment: Don't you want the limit $t\to -i\infty$ to pick out the ground state instead of $t\to +i\infty$?

Comment: @hft Probably. I always get my signs mixed up. Maybe also I am confusing "ground states" with "vacuum states"???

Comment: They usually mean similar things, since it usually takes energy to excite particles.

Comment: Hi zooby. Is this post following a reference wrt. conventions and otherwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Given a (non-relativistic) propagator $K_t(A,B)$ giving the 'conditional amplitude' to go from state $B$ to state $A$ in time $t$, it is known that...

It is helpful to "look inside" this propagator:
$$
K = \langle A|e^{-iHt}|B\rangle\;,
$$
by inserting a complete set of states.

For now, I ignore the degeneracy question and assume each state and each energy can both be labeled by $n$. But, you should be able to work out the general case.

$$
K = e^{-iE_0t}\sum_n \langle A|n\rangle\langle n|B\rangle e^{-i(E_n - E_0) t}\;,
$$
where $E_n - E_0$ is positive for all $n\neq 0$.

Therefore, when we send $t$ to $-i\infty$ every state other than the ground state in the sum is weighted by an exponential that goes to zero. That is, as $t\to-i\infty$:
$$
e^{+iE_0 t}K \to \langle A|0\rangle\langle 0|B\rangle = \Psi_0(A)\Psi_0(B)^*
$$

> Is there any physical meaning that we are taking the limit to infinity along imaginary time? Or is this just a mathematical trick.

Here it looks more like "just" a mathematical trick. However, there is a connection to statistical physics and the canonical partition function.

> Does this trick fail if there are multiple vacuums?

You will end up projecting onto all the states with the lowest energy like, e.g., if there are two ground states:
$$
e^{iE_0 t}K \to \langle A|0_1\rangle\langle 0_1|B\rangle + \langle A|0_2\rangle\langle 0_2|B\rangle 
$$

Comment: Thanks! The way you explained it made it pretty obvious.  So it would seem that the trick fails for degenerate vacuum states. I'm not quite sure what you get instead.

Comment: You get all the vacuum states contributing (like in the example in the very last line of my post for 2 vacuums). So if you want to separate out multiple degenerate vacuum states you need something other than the energy to work with. For example, if the degenerate ground states couple to a magnetic field differently then you could introduce and external field to separate out the degenerate states.

Comment: @hft What if the theory contains a continuum spectrum of energies arbitrarily close to the ground state (like in any theory with massless particles in flat space, for example)? Do I need to implicitly assume some sort of IR regulator that puts a lower bound on the energy of the first excited state (thus making the theory gapped by hand) in order to make sense of this?

Comment: @BrunoDeSouzaLeão I don't know the answer, but you are correct that the analysis does not immediately make sense in the continuum case. I suggest you post an expanded version of your comment as a new question.

Comment: @hft Thank you for the suggestion, I just posted the question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/762023/path-integral-representation-of-the-vacuum-wavefunctional-for-theories-with-mass