# Path integral representation of the vacuum wavefunctional for theories with massless particles

Tags: quantum-field-theory, path-integral, vacuum

The vacuum wavefunctional of a quantum field theory is often generally expressed in terms of a path integral as

\begin{equation}
\langle\Phi(\vec{x})|\Omega\rangle = \int_{\varphi(\tau=0, \vec{x}) = \Phi(\vec{x})} \mathcal{D}\varphi\, e^{-S_E[\varphi]}
\end{equation}
where $|\Omega\rangle$ is the vacuum state, $S_E[\varphi]$ is the Euclidean action for the quantum field $\varphi$, $|\Phi(\vec{x})\rangle$ is a basis of field eigenstates at a constant time (so that $\hat{\varphi}(0, \vec{x})|\Phi(\vec{x})\rangle = \Phi(\vec{x})|\Phi(\vec{x})\rangle$ for some classical field configuration $\Phi(\vec{x})$), and the path integral is performed over the lower half-plane $\tau \leq 0$ in Euclidean time. The usual physicist's derivation of this expression involves some variant of the following steps:

1. Start from the path-integral representation of the time evolution operator $e^{-iHt}$;
2. Perform a Wick rotation $t = -iT$;
3. Send $T\rightarrow +\infty$.

The idea is that the Wick rotation will turn $e^{-iHt}$ into $e^{-HT}$. By then expanding $e^{-HT}$ in a basis of energy eigenstates, all the excited states will come with an exponential factor of $e^{-T\Delta E_i}$ relative to the vacuum state; therefore, when we send $T\rightarrow+\infty$, the overlap with the ground state becomes completely dominant, and we get to the vacuum wavefunctional representation as written above.

I feel that this argument works well when there is a finite energy gap between the vacuum and the first excited state. However, if the theory contains a continuum of states whose energies can be arbitrarily close to that of the vacuum (as is the case with any theory containing massless particles in Minkowski, for example), it is no longer immediate that one could argue that the overlap with the vacuum will be completely dominant in the limit considered. My question then is the following: **is there any additional sublety in the derivation of the expression of the vacuum wavefunctional in terms of a path integral when the theory is gapless?**

On the one hand, I feel like the logic above should go through, since the statement that $e^{-HT}$ projects onto the vacuum state in the limit $T\rightarrow +\infty$ is basically just saying that the zero-temperature limit of a thermal state is the ground state (which always makes sense). On the other hand, the idea that the overlap with the vacuum will be the only term not exponentially damped in the limit of large Euclidean time only makes sense if I make use of something with the effect of an IR regulator. One way out would be to define the theory in a box of finite size with Dirichlet boundary conditions (which does have a finite energy gap between the ground and first excited states), and implicitly take the large-Euclidean-time limit *before* the large-volume limit. Is something like this always being assumed, or is there a better way to make sense of this?